# How do I get the latest message sent on a group chat on whatsapp web as a string using python

Tags: python, html, selenium, whatsapp

**Pretext:**
Im trying to make an app that automates my zoom classes.
the links to which are shared on a whatsapp group that i can open with whatsapp web.

**What I want to do exactly:**
I want to take the latest message in the group chat check if it is text, then check if it contains a link.
If it does I want to extract the link and assign it to a variable, and finally open it in a browser and start the class

---

> the problem is I have no idea how to get the latest message that is
> sent in the group chat

---

***Please Help!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put in an array all the WebElements with the `span` tag.
Cycle trough it checking if a span has a `data-icon` property.
If you find it cycle trough his children using JS until u find an `a` tag with a `href` property. Save it and break.

To find the last one, just cycle in the reverse order.